# RSS feed validator reporting errors for values which are correct

Tags: validation, rss, feed

I am running some of our RSS feeds through a feed validator.

One of the metadata fields is an authors name, but for some reason the validator is expecting to see an email address, images below:

[feed validator result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkIRR.png)

[feed original meta data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVegI.png)

Does anyone have any idea as to why the validator is expecting to see an email address here?

Answer (score 0):

The [RSS specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#ltauthorgtSubelementOfLtitemgt) requires an email address in an item's `author` element, not a name.

You can include a name along with an email address like this:

```
<author>ian.beale@example.com (Ian Beale)</author>
```

If you would prefer to identify the author by name instead of email, omit the `author` element and add the dc:creator element from the Dublin Core namespace, as in this example:

```
<dc:creator>Ian Beale</dc:creator>
```

For more information on adding an element from this namespace (or others), read the [RSS Best Practices Profile](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#namespace-elements-dublin).